# How to add multiple expandable TextViews

Tags: android

In my layout I made a LinearLayout with multiple ScrollViews in it, it's supposed to hold a FAQs section there, in the Scrollviews I added multiple expandable TextViews.
The problem is when I just have one it works very fine, when I however add a expandable TextView to the second ScrollView, the Activity keeps crashing and design time shows rendering problems here is my layout code commenting out the second expandable TextView would make it work:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linkbot"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linkbot"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linkbot"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/linkbot"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linkbot"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/faq1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_above="@+id/faq2"
            >

            <com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView
                android:id="@+id/expandable_text_view1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"


                app:animDuration="200"
                app:maxCollapsedLines="1"

                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/expandable_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"



                         />

                    <ImageButton

                        android:id="@+id/expand_collapse"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:padding="14dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"  />

                </LinearLayout>

            </com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView>


        </ScrollView>
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/faq2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView
                android:id="@+id/expandable_text_view2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"


                app:animDuration="200"
                app:maxCollapsedLines="1"

                >

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/expandable_text2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        />

                    <ImageButton

                        android:id="@+id/expand_collapse2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:padding="14dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView>




        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have in both ScrollView's `@+id/expandable_text`/`@+id/expandable_text2` and `@+id/expand_collapse`/`@+id/expand_collapse2`. Just substitute both with `@id/expandable_text` and `@id/expand_collapse` respectively and it will work fine.

If you notice on the ExpandableTextView library [documentation](https://github.com/Manabu-GT/ExpandableTextView), it says that TextView and ImageButton ids inside `ExpandableTextView` must be set to `@id/expandable_text` and `@id/expand_collapse`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply I guess its ok now

Comment: You can do it this way `expandableTextView1 = (ExpandableTextView)findViewById(R.id.expandable_text_view1)‌​; ` and call directly the `setText` method on it. `expandableTextView1.setText("your text")`