# ExpandableListView duplicate id problem - how to fix that?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am trying to make an `Expandable ListView` by following this great tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4XagtQlqS0). The problem that I have is when I want to "add" a second expandable text. The error that I get is ***"Duplicate id @+id/expandable_text originally defined here" And "Duplicate id @+id/expand_collapse, already defined earlier in this layout"***. It is a logical error but in the tutorial does not shown so is there something wrong with my code?

Below you can find my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context=".Body1">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView
        android:id="@+id/expandable_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:maxCollapsedLines="1"
        app:animDuration="200"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/expandable_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textColor="#666"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/expand_collapse"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView>

    <com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView
        android:id="@+id/expandable_text_view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:maxCollapsedLines="1"
        app:animDuration="200"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/expandable_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textColor="#666"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/expand_collapse"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView>
</ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

And the java file:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView;

public class Body1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_body1);
        ExpandableTextView  expandableTextView1 = (ExpandableTextView) findViewById(R.id.expandable_text_view);
        expandableTextView1.setText(getString(R.string.text1));

        ExpandableTextView  expandableTextView2 = (ExpandableTextView) findViewById(R.id.expandable_text_view);
        expandableTextView2.setText(getString(R.string.text2));

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you are using same ids for textview and imagebutton you need to use unique Ids while defining layout views.

change your code as follows

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView
        android:id="@+id/expandable_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:maxCollapsedLines="1"
        app:animDuration="200"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/expandable_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textColor="#666"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/expand_collapse"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView>

    <com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView
        android:id="@+id/expandable_text_view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:maxCollapsedLines="1"
        app:animDuration="200"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/expandable_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textColor="#666"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/expand_collapse"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I am using an ExpandableTextView library that's why I dont have an ExpandableListView. Also according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032610/how-to-add-multiple-expandable-textviews and the tutorial the '@id/expandable_text' and '@id/expand_collapse' have to be the same

Comment: @EdwardCooper Updated answer please check. In your code in first section you are creating id by using `@+id/` you need to use `@id`

Answer (score 0):

Use `R.id.expandable_text_view2` for second expandable textview.

```
ExpandableTextView  expandableTextView1 = (ExpandableTextView) findViewById(R.id.expandable_text_view);
        expandableTextView1.setText(getString(R.string.text1));

        ExpandableTextView  expandableTextView2 = (ExpandableTextView) findViewById(R.id.expandable_text_view2);
        expandableTextView2.setText(getString(R.string.text2));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout there are 2 ImageButton with the same ID. First, change the second ID:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/expand_collapse_two"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In your Java code you declared the same ExpandableTextView:

```
ExpandableTextView  expandableTextView1 = (ExpandableTextView) findViewById(R.id.expandable_text_view);
ExpandableTextView  expandableTextView2 = (ExpandableTextView) findViewById(R.id.expandable_text_view);
```

So you need to change expandableTextView2 to:

```
 ExpandableTextView  expandableTextView2 = (ExpandableTextView) findViewById(R.id.expandable_text_view2);
```

Finally, your layout should looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context=".Body1">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView
        android:id="@+id/expandable_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:maxCollapsedLines="1"
        app:animDuration="200"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/expandable_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textColor="#666"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/expand_collapse"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView>

    <com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView
        android:id="@+id/expandable_text_view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:maxCollapsedLines="1"
        app:animDuration="200"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/expandable_text2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textColor="#666"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/expand_collapse_two"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView>
</ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

And your Java code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView;

public class Body1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_body1);
        ExpandableTextView  expandableTextView1 = (ExpandableTextView) findViewById(R.id.expandable_text_view);
        expandableTextView1.setText(getString(R.string.text1));

        ExpandableTextView  expandableTextView2 = (ExpandableTextView) findViewById(R.id.expandable_text_view2);
        expandableTextView2.setText(getString(R.string.text2));

    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you about your answer! According to the video tutorial and this anwer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032610/how-to-add-multiple-expandable-textviews the '@id/expandable_text' and  '@id/expand_collapse' have to be the same in order to have multiple expandable texts.

Comment: Just noticed the second expandable_text ID was the same of the first. Check out new layout. Now, according to XML there can't be 2 or more elements with the same ID. If you use different IDs doesn't work at all? If not, try using same ID and change only Java code